# mocking S3.listObjectsV2

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would want to moc the call function the call to s3.listObjectV2.

I am only in need of the contents of what's returned.

```
public async init() {
        AWS.config.update({
            region: config.aws.region,
        })

        const s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: config.aws.S3.apiVersion })

        let params = { Bucket: config.aws.S3.ctrPredictorModelBucket }
        const data = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise()
        return data.contents
}
```

Then in the test, I would want to do before every test something like

```
before( () => {

        s3 = mock.mock(AWS.S3)
        // request = mock.mock(AWS.Request)
        
        mock.when(s3.listObjectsV2(mock.anything()).thenReturn(Return_object))
         
    })
```

with Return_objecy only contains what is needed.

But the current way things are set I get an error saying the s3.listObjectsV2 is not a function

Comment: have you tried using moto for mocking AWS services
http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/

Comment: what is that mock library? ( s3.listObjectsV2 *is* a function)

Comment: import mock from 'ts-mockito'